# how to wait for mongoose query result in async function?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a utils file with function:

```
function max_entries_reached(callback){
EntriesCounterDB.getCounter(this.username, function(error, 
    counter){
       if(counter > this.maxentries) callback(true);
       else callback(false);
    }
}
```

Its a simple function that responds true/false based on mongoose query...

```
async function run_checks(){
     while(is_opening_hours()){
          utils.max_entries_reached(async function(maxstop) {
          if (maxstop !== true) {
               await switch_mode();
          }
          await utils.sleep(60*10);
     }
}
```

This code is an infinite loops very fast, it seems to skip all the sleeps etc and just loops in the while loop. I am guessing its calling things async...

I'm trying to accomplish something fairly trivial but can't figure it out.

I just want to be able to run my run_checks() function with:

```
await run_checks();
```

And then wait for the results from mongoose, before running my next async function which is switch_mode()... How can I do this without the super fast looping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongoose callback API is obsolete, as it supports promises for a long time.

It should be:

```
async function max_entries_reached(){
  const counter = await EntriesCounterDB.getCounter(this.username);
  return (counter > this.maxentries);
}
```

Which can be chained as any other promise:

```
 ...
 while(is_opening_hours()){
   const maxstop = await utils.max_entries_reached();
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
async function run_checks(){
         utils.max_entries_reached(async (maxstop) {
         if (maxstop !== true) {
              await switch_mode();
         }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry I updated my question. I left out the while loop which is what is breaking everything. It seems to get stuck in the while loop going at hyper speed...